# is @Transactional not sufficient for transaction management

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have been using `@Transactional` on my spring boot application for transaction management. But today someone told me to use [narayana](http://narayana.io/) for transaction management.

Why do I have to use narayana if spring itself can do transaction management for me.

Comment: Spring is very flexible. Often times using something like narayana does not actually change how you use things like @transactional. It is just a replacement for the actual implementation of transaction management. Spring "doing things itself" is very often spring just selecting a default 3rd-party implementation for its interfaces and functionality. I can't speak to Narayna in particular as I haven't used it. Just wanted to point out it's probably not a "either/or" situation.

Comment: Spring can only handle local transactions. If you need a distributed transaction, that ensures ACIDity over multiple data sources, or over a data source and a JMS engine for example, you need a transaction manager like Narayana. This is documented: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jta

Comment: @JBNizet could you please elaborate in simple layman word. I am a novice programmer.

Comment: Spring boot has integration with Narayana https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html. And here is a link to example for JTA transactions with Spring:https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html, https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/

Comment: @user8710021 Does your application connect to more than one database? If no, then you don't need Narayana. If yes, and your code executes updates against more than one of them in a single transaction, then you need something like Narayana to handle the synchronization of commits across multiple databases. Read about [two-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) if you want to learn more on the topic.

Comment: @Andreas If I understand you clearly if my application doesn't connect multiple databases, use of narayana won't do anything more. Am I right ?

Comment: @user8710021 That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two kind of transaction. `Local transactions` are specific to a single transactional resource like a JDBC connection, whereas `global transactions` can span multiple transactional resources like transaction in a distributed system.

If you need transaction management for distributed system, spring transaction management is not sufficient and narayana will come into play.

From Spring boot docs:

> Spring Boot supports distributed JTA transactions across multiple XA
>   resources by using either an Atomikos or Bitronix embedded transaction
>   manager. JTA transactions are also supported when deploying to a
>   suitable Java EE Application Server.
>
> When a JTA environment is detected, Spring’s JtaTransactionManager is
>   used to manage transactions. Auto-configured JMS, DataSource, and JPA
>   beans are upgraded to support XA transactions. You can use standard
>   Spring idioms, such as @Transactional, to participate in a distributed
>   transaction. If you are within a JTA environment and still want to use
>   local transactions, you can set the spring.jta.enabled property to
>   false to disable the JTA auto-configuration.